# How to pass same parameters to multiple functions?

Tags: f#

I have a bunch of functions that I want to compute with the same inputs. Is there a better way to see the outputs than the way I chose below?

```
open MathNet.Numerics.Distributions

// The functions
let EuVanillaPut S0 K T r sigma = 
    let d1 = (log(S0/K) + (r + sigma ** 2.0 / 2.0) * T)/(sqrt(T)*sigma)
    let d2 = d1 - sqrt(T)*sigma
    K*exp(-r*T)*Normal.CDF(0.0,1.0,-d2) - S0*Normal.CDF(0.0,1.0,-d1)

let BSMdelta S0 K T r sigma = 
    let d1 = (log(S0/K) + (r + sigma ** 2.0 / 2.0) * T)/(sqrt(T)*sigma)
    Normal.CDF(0.0,1.0,d1)

let BSMgamma S0 K T r sigma = 
    let d1 = (log(S0/K) + (r + sigma ** 2.0 / 2.0) * T)/(sqrt(T)*sigma)
    Normal.PDF(0.0,1.0,d1) / (S0 * sigma * sqrt(T))

let BSMvega S0 K T r sigma = 
    let d1 = (log(S0/K) + (r + sigma ** 2.0 / 2.0) * T)/(sqrt(T)*sigma)
    Normal.PDF(0.0,1.0,d1) * S0 * sqrt(T)

let BSMthetacall S0 K T r sigma = 
    let d1 = (log(S0/K) + (r + sigma ** 2.0 / 2.0) * T)/(sqrt(T)*sigma)
    let d2 = d1 - sqrt(T)*sigma
    -S0 * Normal.PDF(0.0,1.0,d1) * sigma / (2.0*sqrt(T)) - r*K*exp(-r*T)*Normal.CDF(0.0,1.0,d2)

let BSMthetaput S0 K T r sigma = 
    let d1 = (log(S0/K) + (r + sigma ** 2.0 / 2.0) * T)/(sqrt(T)*sigma)
    let d2 = d1 - sqrt(T)*sigma
    -S0 * Normal.PDF(0.0,1.0,d1) * sigma / (2.0*sqrt(T)) + r*K*exp(-r*T)*Normal.CDF(0.0,1.0,-d2)

// Calling them all at once on the same inputs
// So ugly! Is there a better way?
(30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 0.02, 0.05)
|> fun (S0, K, T, r, sigma) -> [EuVanillaPut S0 K T r sigma; 
                                BSMdelta S0 K T r sigma; 
                                BSMgamma S0 K T r sigma;
                                BSMvega S0 K T r sigma;
                                BSMthetacall S0 K T r sigma;
                                BSMthetaput S0 K T r sigma]
```

I'm pretty new to F#, should I make a type for this? Should I be using a different data structure as an input for the functions? Any and all pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: Probably this is better suited for codereview.se, but you can always just make a list of the functions and use `List.map`

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with tuples with five elements, a record type is probably nicer to read and handle overall.

Comment: +1 for use of records. It makes later refactoring easier (adding a parameter, for example). You also reduce the chance of mixing up your arguments - they are all floats at the moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, one option is to create a list of functions and then use `List.map` to iterate over all the functions and call them:

```
let results = 
  [ EuVanillaPut; BSMdelta; BSMgamma ] 
  |> List.map (fun f -> f 30.0 25.0 5.0 0.02 0.05)
```

I suppose you'd then also want to extract the individual results - to do that, you can use pattern matching (but you will get a warning, because the compiler cannot know that the number of elements in the list is correct):

```
let [euVanillaPut; bsmdelta; bsmgamma] = results
```

To avoid the warning, you'd have to write:

```
match results with
| [euVanillaPut; bsmdelta; bsmgamma] -> // all good
| _ -> failwith "This should not happen..."
```

Alternatively, you could change the function definition to use tuple (or a record):

```
let EuVanillaPut (S0, K, T, r, sigma) = 
    let d1 = (log(S0/K) + (r + sigma ** 2.0 / 2.0) * T)/(sqrt(T)*sigma)
    let d2 = d1 - sqrt(T)*sigma
    K*exp(-r*T)*Normal.CDF(0.0,1.0,-d2) - S0*Normal.CDF(0.0,1.0,-d1)
```

Then you can define a single tuple to hold the parameters and use it as an argument to multiple functions:

```
let ps = (30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 0.02, 0.05)

let euVanillaPut = EuVanillaPut ps
let bsmdelta = BSMdelta ps
let bsmgamma = BSMgamma ps
```

The first approach is a clever trick, but if you are doing this often, then extracting the individual results from the list will be a bit ugly. The second approach is simpler and makes more sense if you have a lot of functions with the same group of parameters.